# How do I apply $\nabla$ on this expression for a plane wave?

Tags: derivatives, physics, differential-operators

When trying to use the del function on the following equation (1) representing a linearly polarized, monochromatic, plane waves traveling in the z-direction:

$$\textbf{E} (\textbf{r},t) = \textbf{E}_0 e^{i(k_z z- \omega t)} \tag{1}$$

where $k_z$ is the z-component of the vector $k$.

When trying to obtain $\nabla \textbf{E}$, and knowing that there is only a $z$-component on equation (1), I wrote the expression as:

$$\nabla \textbf{E} = \frac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial z} = \textbf{E}_0 e^{-i \omega t} \left[ik_z e^{ik_z z} \right] + ... \tag{2}$$

I am struggling to obtain the second half of this differentiation because $k$ is a z component and **I don't know if that should be simply considered to be a constant or if I should also differentiate it.** If the latter is correct, how must I differentiate it?

Comment: Is equation $(1)$ really supposed to be $$\exp\left[{\color{red}t(k_{z}z-\omega t)}\right]$$ and not $$\exp\left[{\color{blue}i(k_{z}z-\omega t)}\right]$$?

Comment: No, my mistake, it should be an $i$. Thank you so much, but still, my problem with the differentiation stands.

Comment: $k_{z}$ is a _real_ number. So if $E_{0}$ is independent of $z$ (or $x, y,\vec{r}$ for that matter) then there is no 'second half' of the differentiation. You just have $$\partial_{z} E = ik_{z} E_{0} e^{i(k_{z} z - \omega t)}$$

Comment: Oh so it isn't taken as a vector itself, just the magnitude of such vector.Thank you so much